# How to override span-columns at different breakpoint in SUSY

Tags: susy-compass

I think I must be missing something fundamental with how susy works, and the documentation has too few examples to understand how this works.

I want different layouts at different breakpoints.  I can make it that far, but I want my elements to span different number of columns depending on what breakpoint is triggered.  So if I have a general stylesheet for mobile ('mobile-first') like:

```
 .wrapper{
        .element1{
            @include span-columns(4);
        }

        .element2{
            @include span-columns(2 omega);
        }
}
```

But once the width changes to my 'tablet' and it changes to an 8 column layout, I want to be able to change this to:

```
     @include at-breakpoint($tablet-break $tablet-layout){
         .wrapper{
        @include set-container-width;
            .element1{
                @include span-columns(5);
            }

            .element2{
                @include span-columns(3 omega);
            }
    }
}
```

It seems like this not only doesn't 'overwrite' the mobile settings, but it appears, upon firebug inspection, that the elements do not match up with my new tablet columns.  I think it is still using a 6 column layout.  Adding @include set-container-width doesn't seem to fix the problem; however, if I comment out the mobile layout it works.  So it's almost as if these include statements don't overwrite, so I think I'm not understanding how susy works.  Here's an example of firebug showing the element not matching the layout:

[image: columns with span not matching]

(Also I'm not sure of any SUSY best practices (except for don't nest more than 4 deep).  I could define all my sass with nested @at-breakpoint statements for all my changes, or I could define my default (mobile) css and then create a separate sass block all nested within at-breakpoint.  I don't know if this is causing a problem.)

**UPDATE**

It appears, that if I include at-breakpoint includes after the original (mobile) declaration, it seems to work.  Though it does seem to require code repetition:

```
        .element1{
        @include span-columns(2 omega);
        text-indent: -1em;
        text-align: center;
        @include at-breakpoint($tablet-break $tablet-layout){
            @include span-columns(3 omega);
            text-indent: 0;                
            text-align: left;                
        }
        @include at-breakpoint($desktop-break $desktop-layout){
            @include span-columns(3 omega);
            text-indent: 0;
            text-align: left;                                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your initial code should work fine, depending what you are trying to do. Without knowing what you were hoping to see and what you are actually seeing, it's very hard to help. What makes you think it is still using a six-column layout after the breakpoint? What doesn't seem to be overriding, and what is happening instead?

Comment: If I set an @include susy-grid-background I can see the eight column layout that I want, but more importantly, if I check the elements with firefox, I can see that they are not aligned with these columns.  So that a span(4) element will end somewhere in between the edges of column 4 (based on the susy-grid-background

Comment: Eric I added a picture showing the problem.  It seems I have ran into the problem again.  If I define a default layout and then try and reset the grid for desktop with the 'container' or 'set-container-width' mixin then I can't redeclare a new span-columns mixin on the element because it uses the default (mobile) layout.  I have to go to the default (mobile) block and set an at-breakpoint condition immediately after the default property to get this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see the problems your describing shown in the code you've posted. Can you post a complete demonstration of the problem? If you are having specificity issues, that's generally out of Susy's control. There's nothing magic happening here - Susy just creates a media-query and uses new settings for calculations inside the breakpoint.