# Override span-columns() at-breakpoint in SUSY

Tags: grid, susy-compass

The question has already been asked, but the solution doesn't help me any further.

[How to override span-columns at different breakpoint in SUSY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940363/how-to-override-span-columns-at-different-breakpoint-in-susy)

**screen.css.scss**

```
// Settings

$total-columns  : 6;
$column-width   : 4em;
$gutter-width   : 1em;
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;

$tablet         : 8;
$desktop         : 12;

// Layout

body {
    @include container($total-columns, $tablet, $desktop);
    .logo {
        @include span-columns(4);
    }
    nav {
        @include span-columns(2 omega);
    }
}

@include at-breakpoint($tablet) {
    .logo {
        @include span-columns(5, $tablet);
    }
    nav {
        @include span-columns(3 omega, $tablet);
    }
}

@include at-breakpoint($desktop) {
    .logo {
        @include span-columns(1, $desktop);
    }
    nav {
        @include span-columns(11 omega, $desktop);
    }
}
```

This is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/jmdcp/1/

When changing the browser width, the columns don't resize. They keep the default ratio (span-columns(4) and span-columns(2 omega), even at the tablet and desktop breakpoint.
I really don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a cascade specificity issue. Your initial span settings are nested under the body selector. Your breakpoint overrides are not. If you nest it all under body, or un-nest the initial settings it works:

```
body {
  @include container($total-columns, $tablet, $desktop);
}

.logo {
  @include span-columns(4);
  @include at-breakpoint($tablet) {
    @include span-columns(5);
  }
  @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {
    @include span-columns(1);
  }
}

nav {
  @include span-columns(2 omega);
  @include at-breakpoint($tablet) {
    @include span-columns(3 omega);
  }
  @include at-breakpoint($desktop) {
    @include span-columns(11 omega);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the problem! Is there a way to make the CSS a little bit more DRY?

Comment: Yep, if all you need to override inside the breakpoints is width, use `width: columns(11);` instead of e.g. `@include span-columns(11 omega);`. You might sometimes (on the logo) also have to override the gutter with `margin-right: gutter();`.